# JS timeout in for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, web, delay

I want to print something and set a timeout for the next iteration.
for example: 1 --> 2s delay --> 2 --> 2s delay --> 3 --> ...

```
 for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
       console.log("index: "+ i);
        setTimeout(() => {
        }, coffeeMachine.shoppingCard.list[i].time * 1000);
    }
}
```

This would print:

```
0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 --> 2s delay
```

But I want this:

```
 1 --> 2s delay --> 2 --> 2s delay --> 3 -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When processing an iterable, like `coffeeMachine.shoppingCard.list` in your example, it is more efficient to process it as such...

The example below makes use of [iter-ops](https://github.com/vitaly-t/iter-ops) library:

```
import {pipeAsync, delay} from 'iter-ops';

const i = pipeAsync(
                     coffeeMachine.shoppingCard.list,
                     delay(a => a.time * 1000)
                   ); //=> AsyncIterable

// process your list:
for await (const a of i) {
    console.log('value:', a);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Modern JS has something called `async / await`.

If you wrap a setTimeout into a Promise constructor you can fake a delay, and use `await delay(ms)` on this Promise.

As mentioned in comments, MDN has some good docs on `async / await` -> [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await)

eg.

```js
const delay = ms => new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms));

async function test() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    console.log("index: "+ (i + 1));
    await delay(2000);
  }
}

test();
```

Comment: Based on the output the OP wants it should be `i + 1`.

Comment: OP here's some documentation for [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises#async_and_await).

Comment: @Andy  yeah, I  just copied the OP's code here, I've updated so it's more like the OP's output..